# Finding Sub Spans within Element XPath using Protractor Framework

Tags: javascript, xpath, protractor

I have the following lines of code:

```
.then(function click(services) {
                var tryItElement;

                if (services.length < 1) {
                    return;
                }

                buttonElement = element(by.xpath('//div[@class="my-class" and contains(., \'' + services[0].title + '\')]//span[contains(., \'Button Text\')]'));
                return browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(buttonElement), getWaitTime())
                    .then(function() {
                        return buttonElement.getWebElement();
                    })
                    .then(function(buttonElement) {
                        var protocol = url.parse(services[0].actionUrl).protocol;
                        if (protocol === null) {
                            throw new Error('expected ' + protocol + ' not to be null');
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function() {
                        return buttonElement.click();
                    })
                    .then(function() {
                        return browser.wait(helper.ExpectedConditions.responseCompleted(proxy, services[0].actionUrl), getWaitTime());
                    })
                    .then(function() {
                        return browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
                    })
                    .then(function() {
                        return click(services.slice(1));
                    })
            })
            .catch(fail)
            .then(done);
```

I expect the first to find an element on my page with the class that contains some text as specified from `services[0].title`. It does and the following line finds a span within that element that contains the text `Button Text`.

I have this in a loop and for some reason, the `buttonElement` stays the same even though performing the action manually in the Chrome dev tools gives me the expected results.

Any other ways of trying this or suggestions? I can clarify some more if needed.

Comment: What is this .first() method in the tryItElement can you post the block code thanks

Comment: It's recursive. It sits in a function block that calls a function called `click(services)` using the syntax `return click(services.slice(1));`

Comment: Can you post all of your code including the loop

Comment: if I remember my XPATH, by using `//span` you will always find the first `span` in the whole "document" rather than the first `span` "below" the given contextNode (which may be `labServiceElement` - I don't know what `by.xpath` is) - try using `.//span` to find spans beneath the given contextNode

Comment: I'm using the Protractor test framework if that clarifies some